# Java conversion to base 7

Tags: java, math, radix

I have been trying to understand a code of a program that converts decimal to the base of 7. I do understand everything until the point where the given loop begins. Could you explain me that?

```
do {
    char digit = (char) (number % 7 + '0');
    s = digit + s;
    number /= 7;
} while (number > 0);
System.out.print(s);
```

Comment: That's the usual modulo/divison trick, you find it [all over the place](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_logical_organization/number_system_conversion.htm)

Comment: my fault, I edited it now

Comment: I do understand the logic behind it, but I do not understand the "do" in the  loop with (char) and the '0'

Comment: Is `s` of type `String`?

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it seems it is mainly this line

```
char digit = (char) (number % 7 + '0');
```

you do not understand.

It converts the value of `number % 7`, which is an integer, to a digit as a character. The character codes of the digits are successive with 48 for '0', 49 for '1', and so on. Adding a number between 0 and 9 (inclusive) to the character code of '0' gives you the character code of the corresponding digit.

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
} while (number > 0);
```

is a normal `do-while`-loop which is only slightly different to a `while`-loop in the way that it checks the `while`-condition only after the body has been evaluated, not before as a `while`-loop would do.

```
char digit = (char) (number % 7 + '0');
```

is converting a digit from a number to a character. `'0'` needs to be added to the number because the number `0` is not the same as the character `'0'` (see ASCII tables for example) and therefore adding the character offset `'0'` to a digit (e. g. `7`) will result in the number representing the character `'7'` and not the symbol at position `8` (0-based) in the character set.

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is, I think, the fact that char(7) doesn't give 7 as a character but rather the 7th character in the ASCII table.

Doing number modulo 7 will give you a number between 0 and 6, the rest of the division by 7. But if you want to convert it to a char, you need to find that number's index in the ASCII table. That index will be zero's index plus that number hence

```
char digit = (char) (number % 7 + '0');
```

Now, I'm not sure it's necessary to use char at all... You can concatenate a string with a number.